# Как в pythonanywhere добавить документ doc?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pythonanywhere

Я сделал телеграмм-бота и одна из его функций — это высылать doc файл. На компьтере я указывал путь к нему, и все работало, а как это сделать в pythonanywhere, я не знаю. Мне нужен именно `.doc`.

Comment: покажите, как выглядит ваше обращение к файлу .doc внутри кода

Answer (score 0):

Так же точно, просто сделайте импорт внутри кода с ботом этого doc файла, и загрузите в папке с ботом на pythonanywhere